# How to convert a mp3 string into sound using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I used ajax to fetch a mp3 file from the server as a string by using "file_get_contents" method. Now i want to convert that string back to actual sound so that it can be played using js. I'm a bit new to php. Any help would be appreciated. The exact lines of my php code are -

```
<?php
$file = "txa.mp3";
$fx1 = fopen($file, "rb");
$fx2 = file_get_contents($file);
echo $fx2;
exit();
```

I want to convert the string back into original sound using Javascript or any of its implementations or if anyone has any better way of streaming audio without letting users know the actual path of the file then let me know.

Comment: Play it from the url and the browser handles the rest?

Comment: can you explain how? @NathanielFlick

Comment: html5 comes with the audio element to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass that file content to html5 audio tag, and attribute src

Kind of

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/mp3;base64,HERE YOUR CONTENT OF $fx2">
```

And if you want to use javascript for this reason you might use DOM selectors to set that value to attribute src.

Comment: If you would like to provide that mp3 by ajax and js you have to use that. Or just file path.